# Raspberry Pi system crashes at file transfer

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have an external 1TB Hard Drive, and I usb-connect it to the Pi's usb slot, and I mount it like this (the whole drive is one partition):

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g  -o rw,uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /mnt/book/` and the mount goes through fine.

When I try to copy some large folder [using sftp] , that has many files, some of them are one big contiguous file that reaches 5 GB per file (it's a virtual machine), but the Pi's system crash at 1GB of file transfer (some times less than that), that I have to disconnect the power cable and reconnect it again ... what could be the reason??

**-- Edit --**

Source: my computer, destination: the hard drive connected to RPi

Both RPi and my computer are connected wirelessly through my wireless router.

P.S. I'm have raspbian installed on Raspberry Pi.

**-- Edit 2 --**

those are ssh logs in auth.log

`tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

```
raspberrypi sshd[2077]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.0.3 port 47018 ssh2
raspberrypi sshd[2077]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
raspberrypi CRON[2183]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
raspberrypi CRON[2183]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
raspberrypi sshd[2191]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.0.3 port 47125 ssh2
raspberrypi sshd[2191]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
raspberrypi sshd[2198]: subsystem request for sftp by user pi
raspberrypi sudo:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw,uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /mnt/book/
raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

And those logs didn't change before and after the failure !!!

On my computer, I took a snapshot for the failure when it happens:

[image]

Comment: Are you copying _to_ the drive or _from_ the drive? What is the source and what is the destination?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and edit has been added to my post.

Comment: Does the sftp server run on "your computer" or the pi? Try enabling sftp logs and have a look at the output. http://serverfault.com/questions/73319/sftp-logging-is-there-a-way

Comment: @Bex, sftp server runs on my pi

Comment: Great. What log output do you get?

Comment: @Bex, check Edit 2 in my question

Answer (score 1):

It is said that SFTP can actually still suffer from potential issues related to ASCII/binary transmission modes. So you can try using "scp" instead of "sftp"